# C# - Create MD5 hash for files and files in subdirectories and write it to textfile

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a simple Windows Console Application which does the following:

Create a MD5 hash for each file in a given folder and write the filename including the file's directories and the generated hash in a textfile.
I am able to create the hashes and write the filename with the hash into a textfile.
The part which i can't solve is the thing where I write the filename with its directory in front of it.

An example:

my root directory is `C:\temp`

In `C:\temp`I have 3 files:

`a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt`.
Furthermore there are 2 folders inside `C:\temp`:

`001`and `002`

`001` contains 3 other files and `002` contains some files and another directory.

Roughly said what I want my output to be is:

```
a.txt 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg2
b.txt 8pilZcutPpW5x6atctbWWQ2
c.txt 7wGB3hjvOVGAbArWO4l7pA2
001\d.txt _Uqz2gB17nv1Vxrh-MPrCw2
001\e.txt 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg2
001\f.txt _Uqz2gB17nv1Vxrh-MPrCw2
002\g.txt 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg2
002\h.txt 7wGB3hjvOVGAbArWO4l7pA2
002\test\i.txt _Uqz2gB17nv1Vxrh-MPrCw2
002\test\j.txt 7wGB3hjvOVGAbArWO4l7pA2
```

My current output is

```
a.txt 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg2
b.txt 8pilZcutPpW5x6atctbWWQ2
c.txt 7wGB3hjvOVGAbArWO4l7pA2
d.txt _Uqz2gB17nv1Vxrh-MPrCw2
e.txt 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg2
f.txt _Uqz2gB17nv1Vxrh-MPrCw2
g.txt 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg2
h.txt 7wGB3hjvOVGAbArWO4l7pA2
i.txt _Uqz2gB17nv1Vxrh-MPrCw2
j.txt 7wGB3hjvOVGAbArWO4l7pA2
```

This is my current code. I am thankful for any advice or hints to make my code better.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

namespace MD5_Generator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MD5 Hash Generator");
            Console.WriteLine("This program creates MD5 hashes for all files in the folder.");
            Console.WriteLine("Work in progress...");
            string root = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string hashList = root + "/hashList.txt";            
            if (!File.Exists(hashList))
            {
                var initHastListFile = File.Create(hashList);
                initHastListFile.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                File.Delete(hashList);
                var hastListFile = File.Create(hashList);
                hastListFile.Close();
            }
            int i = 0;
            string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string[] lines = new string[allFiles.Count()];

            lines = DirSearch(root, lines, i);
            File.AppendAllLines(hashList, lines);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static string[] DirSearch(string dir, string[] lines, int counter)
        {
            string hashListFileName = "hashList.txt";
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
            {
                //2. Create an MD5 hash per file
                using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
                {
                    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(f);
                    string filename = info.FullName;
                    if (filename != hashListFileName)
                    {
                        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
                        {
                            byte[] fileMD5 = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                            string hash = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(fileMD5);
                            string currDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);                         
                            lines[counter] = info.Name + " " + hash;                            
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
            {
                DirSearch(d, lines, counter);
            }

            return lines;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should propably make this a proper CSV file, using any of the 100 existing CSV Parsers/creators. You already got 3 values to store: Path, filename, hashvalue. Those also tend to take care/warn you about any issues with any special charcters (like the '\').

Comment: @Christopher I want to upload the generated textfile and all the files which are written inside of it to a central server. Other people start another program which downloads this textfile. Based on the hashes the application decides if the file of the current line has to be downloaded from the server.

Comment: Using hashes to look for file changes should be the last option, not the first one. Even most commercial backup programms will not go to that level. It will look at filesize and last change date. Hashes are usually left to "verify integrity" scans and similar repair operations. Also the moment you threw in a Server/Client architecture, you pretty much said you will need a proper DB on the server side.

Comment: Excuse me, I wanted to say that the files are stored on a FTP Server. I want to compare the hashes of files on a local machine against the hashes of the files stored on the FTP Server.
But thank you for your advice to use filesizes and the last changed date.

Comment: A quick subnote if I were working on efficiency; I'd probably check file size (if they match, continue), select a random middle point in the file and read say 200 bytes (give or take) from both files, if they are the same, check the hash, if they are not you know they are different. Hashing has to read the entire file and put it through a one way algorithm so it is fairly time consuming and takes allot of resources, no need to hash a file that clearly is not the same as another. At the same time, I use hashing for verification allot more than I should :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this i guess

**Method**

```
public static IEnumerable<(string fileName, string hash)> GetHasList(string path, bool isRelative)
{
   foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
   {
      string hash;
      using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
         using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file))
            hash = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(md5.ComputeHash(stream));
      if (isRelative)
         yield return (file.Remove(0, path.TrimEnd('/').Length+1), hash);
      else
         yield return (file, hash);
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
string output = Path.Combine(@"D:\", "hashList.txt");

// format results
var data = GetHasList(@"D:\Temp",true).Select(x => $"{x.fileName} {x.hash}");

// write file
File.WriteAllLines(output, data);
```

If you want to make it a bit more fault tolerant of spaces

```
// format results
var data = GetHasList(@"D:\Temp",true).Select(x => $"\"{x.fileName}\" {x.hash}");
```

**Output**

```
"2284804723016.xml" UBtEG5qItCVKf8VTdamoCQ2
"2301708833016.xml" vRiXj012Q9RlU9xEgZPjcA2
"New folder\2320158695015.xml" hpDYqQuy_wvQMD5tOMJxjA2
"New folder\2282121972016.xml" j-Y06SdEM3kHjbhTIqhTKg2
"New folder (2)\2281419740016.xml" 3GWrCgtrda-W4ymCNSi4MA2
"New folder (2)\2281593123016.xml" ncqGPehpHflpzjl0j0nFfQ2
```

Comment: That returns the wrong output, he wants the relative path to the root that was passed in to GetHasList

Comment: Thank you fr your detailed answer, @TheGeneral.
@ScottChamberlain is right, I want to get rid of the "D:\Temp\" part.

And somehow the Method you wrote gives me an error of `System.IO.IOException: `
The file is used by another process. Maybe I can fix that by myself.

Comment: @Klappstuhl updated, it does relative paths, and your error is because you have a file open

Comment: @TheGeneral Thank you! I modified it myself a bit but this is good and works!

Answer (score 0):

I now did it with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

namespace MD5_Generator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("MD5 Hash Generator");
            Console.WriteLine("This program creates MD5 hashes for all files in the folder.");
            Console.WriteLine("Work in progress...");
            string root = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string hashList = root + "/hashList.txt";            
            if (!File.Exists(hashList))
            {
                var initHastListFile = File.Create(hashList);
                initHastListFile.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                File.Delete(hashList);
                var hastListFile = File.Create(hashList);
                hastListFile.Close();
            }
            int i = 0;
            string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string[] lines = new string[allFiles.Count()];

            lines = DirSearch(root, lines, i, root);
            File.AppendAllLines(hashList, lines);

            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        static string[] DirSearch(string dir, string[] lines, int counter, string root)
        {
            string hashListFileName = "hashList.txt";
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
            {
                //2. Create an MD5 hash per file
                using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
                {
                    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(f);
                    string filename = info.FullName;
                    if (filename != hashListFileName)
                    {
                        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
                        {
                            byte[] fileMD5 = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                            string hash = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(fileMD5);
                            string currDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);                         
                            lines[counter] = info.FullName.Substring(root.Length+1) + " " + hash;                            
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
            {
                DirSearch(d, lines, counter, root);
            }

            return lines;
        }
    }
}
```

I just used the Substring Method to 'cut off' the not relevant parts where `root` is `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();` :

`lines[counter] = info.FullName.Substring(root.Length+1) + " " + hash;`

The result looks exactly like I want it to be!

```
MD5_Generator.exe NVt6BVhZyy0QQPA-Cumntg2
MD5_Generator.exe.config 7wGB3hjvOVGAbArWO4l7pA2
MD5_Generator.pdb _M_l1ka8Jg_c0LOtbXfF6g2
System.ValueTuple.dll mc7Hfb7gqxC5_E1SodQUvg2
System.ValueTuple.xml So9YKXUqAxilrTjfmxgVPQ2
Test\123.txt 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg2
Test\Test2\dhf9.txt 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg2
```

Thank you for contributing!